# C# visual studio 2013 How can I replace DLL for installed version

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, installshield

I created a GUI app in C# with installer, the installer place DLLs in the installation directory I want to be able to replace the DLL and run the application (the new DLL has the same name and was build in the same manner). I tried to do that: while the program is not running and then run but when I tried to run the program it reconfigured itself -  "Please wait while Windows configure ProgramName".
Does any one got idea how I can do what i'm trying to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: re-build the setup.msi with the new dll and re-installing your program is not an option?

Comment: It's exactly what I'm trying to avoid..

Comment: Has the version number changed significantly across builds?

Comment: Hasn't changed at all.